# Using Datatables AltEditor requested unkown parameter

Tags: ajax, flask, datatable, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm having trouble with [Datatable AltEditor](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor) when trying to update rows.

Btw, I'm using flask as back-end.

This is my setup:

First I'll show you what the datatable looks like

[image: Datatables example]

Html table:

```
<div id='contenidoBienvenida'>
    <table class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example" style="width: 100%">

    </table>
</div>
```

Flask Routes:

```
@app.route('/getProfesores') #This route sends the json data with all the teachers
def getProfesores():
    if 'numEmpleado' in session:
        try:
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM usuarios")
            r = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value)  # IF NULO hacer algo
                      for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
            if (len(r) == 0):
                return "No hay profesores"
            return json.dumps({'data': r})
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


#This route receives the desired data to be edited, saves changes and returns new data as JSON
@app.route('/editar/profesor/', methods=['GET']) 
def editarProfesor():
    if 'numEmpleado' in session:
        try:
            numEmpleado = request.args.get('NumEmpleado')
            nombre = request.args.get('nombre')
            password = request.args.get('password')
            correo = request.args.get('correo')
            tipoCuenta = request.args.get('tipoCuenta')
            perfilCompletado = request.args.get('perfilCompletado')

            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            query = "UPDATE usuarios SET NumEmpleado = %s, nombre = %s, password = %s, correo = %s, tipoCuenta = %s, perfilCompletado = %s WHERE NumEmpleado = %s"
            cur.execute(query, (numEmpleado,nombre,password,correo,tipoCuenta,perfilCompletado,numEmpleado))
            mysql.connection.commit() #Execute the update sql

            cur.execute( #Now it grabs the edited row
                "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios.NumEmpleado=%s" %
                numEmpleado)
            r = cur.fetchone()
            cur.close()
            return json.dumps({'data': r}) #sends the edited row as JSON -- SUCCESS
        except Exception as e:
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

profesoresDatatable.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var columnDefs = [{
    data: "NumEmpleado",
    title: "Número Empleado",
  },
  {
    data: "nombre",
    title: "Nombre"
  },
 {
    data: "password",
    title: "Password"
  },
 {
    data: "correo",
    title: "Mail"
  },
 {
    data: "tipoCuenta",
    title: "Tipo Cuenta"
  },
 {
    data: "perfilCompletado",
    title: "¿perfilCompletado?"
  }];

  var myTable;

  // local URLs are not allowed
  var url_ws_mock_get = './getProfesores'; #Flask route which fill the datatable
  var url_ws_mock_ok = './mock_svc_ok.json'; #not used

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    destroy: true,
    responsive: true,
    ajax: {
        url : url_ws_mock_get, #Flask route to obtain json data
        // our data is an array of objects, in the root node instead of /data node, so we need 'dataSrc' parameter
        dataSrc : 'data'
    },
    columns: columnDefs,

        dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
        select: 'single',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Agregar',
            name: 'add'        // do not change name
        },
        {
            extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
            text: 'Editar',
            name: 'edit'        // do not change name
        },
        {
            extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
            text: 'Borrar',
            name: 'delete'      // do not change name
        },
        {
            text: 'Refrescar',
            name: 'refresh'      // do not change name
        }],
        onAddRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
            $.ajax({
                // a tipycal url would be / with type='PUT'
                url: url_ws_mock_ok,
                type: 'GET',
                data: rowdata,
                success: success,
                error: error
            });
        },
        onDeleteRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
            $.ajax({
                // a tipycal url would be /{id} with type='DELETE'


   url: url_ws_mock_ok,
            type: 'GET',
            data: rowdata,
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
    },
    onEditRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) { 
        $.ajax({
            // a tipycal url would be /{id} with type='POST'
            url: './editar/profesor/', #flask route which save changes and returns edited row as JSON
            type: 'GET',
            data: rowdata,
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
    }
  });


});
```

In the following example I will change the password for the user named Arturo Casanova, from '123' to 'password'

[image]

When I have finished editing and I click on save changes I get a warning about requested unknown parameters.

[image]

When I close the warning I get the success message

[image]

But the edited row is not inserted correctly

[image]

If I click on the Refrescar button(refresh button),it then will appear on the datatable correctly

[image]

This is the [current JSON obtained by Flask Route'/getProfesores')](https://api.myjson.com/bins/19art7)

This is the [JSON response after editing the row](https://api.myjson.com/bins/107agj), the one that now should appear on the datatable

This are the scripts I'm using

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-colvis-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/r-2.2.2/sl-1.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/dataTables.altEditor.free.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/profesoresDatatable.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was posted a while ago but I'll repsond as I had exactly the same problem, and also because I got in touch with the developers of the altEditor who responded below with a comment about the proposed fix.

The reason that the fix works is that it uses the JSON that the browser sent to the server, and it's valid JSON.

Without the proposed fix the editor uses the JSON returned by your server and I think you will find that this is where the problem is. As long as your server returns valid JSON with a key/value pair for each column in your table, it will work.

As an example, here's my table:

[image: Example table]

In the function called by onEditRow I create a string containing keys and values and then encode it to JSON and return it:

```
$row = '{"client_number": "1", "name": "Mark", "phone": "89797979", "link": "http://someserver.com"}';
echo json_encode($row);
```

With that code when I click the edit button on any row it will display the record from the table. When I click to close the edit dialog the row in the table will change to show that $row I returned. If you try that it should be enough to demonstrate that with valid JSON containing a value for each column, the editor works.

When I look in the browser to see what it received from the call to the server, it shows this:

[image: Browser Network Tab]

And finally, here's the table after closing the edit dialog box. It shows that record I returned:

[image]

Obviously your server function will need to deal with the actual record clicked on and generate $row from that.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working

I changed the line 285 of dataTables.altEditor.free.js

that._editRowCallback(*data*,b,c,d,e); **changed to** that._editRowCallback(*rowDataArray*,b,c,d,e);

Complete section:

```
that.onEditRow(that,
                    rowDataArray,
                    function(data,b,c,d,e){ that._editRowCallback(rowDataArray,b,c,d,e); },
                    function(data){ that._errorCallback(data);
                });
```

And now it doesn't show warnings and it refreshes as it should do

Comment: Thanks for reporting the solution back, this helped me tonight!

Comment: I'm glad it could helped you out! @NathanPond

Comment: IMHO this is not a good solution. ´rowDataArray´ is the data that the browser sent to the server, while ´data´ is the data that the server returned to the client. This means that you are ignoring every server-side modification to your data. Probably you have to better analyze what server returns. If you *really* what to ignore server-side stuff, you should modify the function ´onEditRow´ passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but Mark's answer seems to be the correct one per the documentation on github.

> AJAX Setup
>
> The datatable accepts the following callback functions as arguments:
>
> onAddRow(alteditor, rowdata, success, error)
> onEditRow(alteditor, rowdata, success, error, originalrowdata)
> onDeleteRow(alteditor, rowdata, success, error)
>
> In the most common case, these function should call $.ajax as expected
> by the webservice. The two functions success and error should be
> passed as arguments to $.ajax.
>
> Within the procedures onAddRow, onEditRow, onDeleteRow, you can access
> datatable object using alteditor.s.dt.
>
> **Webservice must return the modified row in JSON format, because the
> success() function expects this. Otherwise you have to write your own
> success() callback (e.g. refreshing the whole table).**

There needs to be a matching JSON response with the modified data to update the record natively