Error after Adding new row in Datatables and altEditor
I am adding this screen to a very old application that was build in Struts 1.3, EJB 2.0.
Trying Dynamic Add/Edit/Delete/Refresh rows. Using Datatables and altEditor. Following this example: https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor/tree/master/example/03_ajax_objects
When I click on Add button and enter all details, I am calling my ajax call (inside onAddRow function) to save the new record and the Save works. But I am getting error as shown in picture.
I see it does the ajax call and I see the date saved in database. And on the screen, when I click on Refresh, it displays the new record.
Any help please. I am not getting any clue where is the error.
    $( document ).ready(function() {        
    var context = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
    
    var columnDefs = [
     {
       data: "payMonth",
       title: "Month",
       type: "number"
     },
    {
       data: "payYear",
       title: "Year",
       type: "number"
     },
     {
       data: "payPercentage",
       title: "Percentage",
       type: "number"
     }
     ];
    let someId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function() {$('#loader').show();},
        complete: function() { $('#loader').hide();},
        success: function() {},
        async: true
    });
    var url1 = context + '/myAction.do?action=myGetMethods&someId='+someId;
    var url2 = context+'/myAction.do?action=mySaveMethod&someId='+someId; 
    
    var myTable;
    myTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        ajax: {
            url : url1,
            dataSrc : 'data'
        },
        columns: columnDefs,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
        select: 'single',
        responsive: true,
        altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add'        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Edit',
                name: 'edit'        // do not change name
            },
            {
                extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                text: 'Delete',
                name: 'delete'      // do not change name
            },
            {
                text: 'Refresh',
                name: 'refresh'      // do not change name
            }
        ],
        onAddRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
            var payPercentage = rowdata.payPercentage;
            var payMonth = rowdata.payMonth;
            var payYear = rowdata.payYear;
            var urlSave = context+'/myAction.do?action=mySaveMethod&someId='+someId;
            $.ajax({
                url: urlSave,
                type: 'GET',
                data: rowdata,
                success: success,
                error: error
            });
        },
        onDeleteRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url1,
                type: 'GET',
                data: rowdata,
                success: success,
                error: error
            });
        },
        onEditRow: function(datatable, rowdata, success, error) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url1,
                type: 'GET',
                data: rowdata,
                success: success,
                error: error
            });
        }
    });
});




Did you review and follow the troubleshooting guide given in the error message? What conclusions did you reach? Add those to the question.

What is the Ajax response from the call in onAddRow? Show us that response, by adding the JSON (as text, please) to the body of your question (don't add it here as a comment). Make sure the JSON contains a full representation of a row of data for DataTables to consume.

You can see an example here from that demo you linked to, showing what JSON is used to populate the table at the start. It's an array of objects. And you can similarly see here what one updated row looks like for the altEditor Ajax response. It's a single object representing one row of data. Do you follow these structures (but using your field names)?

I found the solution from here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857141/using-datatables-alteditor-requested-unkown-parameter) , My response from backend was coming a list of array. I changed to one single object, then it worked. Thanks for trying to help me. I still have another question. How to Validation when I ad a new record and onChange of drop down.

Glad you solved it. I flagged this question as having an answer here:  Using Datatables AltEditor requested unkown parameter
